# Visualization extra data on eventHover of EventDrops.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I'm developing an little tool using `Eventdrops.js` version 0.2.0 . I'm using this version because I need only the `javascript` file without extra stuff like nodejs and other things. I'm succesfully plot the data on the chart, but my problem is show extra data on `eventhover` event. I'm using the following to generate my data and the code that handle the event:

**javascript code**

```
    data = [{name: "(X)       - Erro", dates: XdataErro.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),    data: XdataErro.map(function(a){return a.message;}),       color: "red"},
            {name: "(X)       - Info", dates: XdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),   data: XdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.message;}),       color: "green"},
            {name: "(X - AC)  - Erro", dates: XACdataErro.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),   data: XACdataErro.map(function(a){return a.message;}),     color: "red"},
            {name: "(X - AC)  - Info", dates: XACdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),   data: XACdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.message;}),     color: "green"},                
            {name: "(AC - X)  - Erro", dates: ACXdataErro.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),   data: ACXdataErro.map(function(a){return a.message;}),     color: "red"},
            {name: "(AC - X)  - Info", dates: ACXdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),   data: ACXdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.message;}),     color: "green"},
            {name: "(Y-X) - Erro", dates: YXdataErro.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),data: YXdataErro.map(function(a){return a.message;}),  color: "red"},
            {name: "(Y-X) - Info", dates: YXdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),data: YXdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.message;}),  color: "green"},
            {name: "(X-Y) - Erro", dates: XYdataErro.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),data: XYdataErro.map(function(a){return a.message;}),  color: "red"},
            {name: "(X-Y) - Info", dates: XYdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.timestamp;}).reverse(),data: XYdataInfo.map(function(a){return a.message;}),  color: "green"}];

    var eventDropsChart = d3.chart.eventDrops();


    eventDropsChart.start(startTime)
            .width(window.innerWidth)
            .eventLineColor(function(e){
            console.log(e);
            return e.color;
            }).eventHover((n) => {
              var series = n.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML;
              var timestamp = d3.select(n).data()[0];
              var message = d3.select(n).data()[1];
              document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = 'Mensagem = '+message+ ' \nTempo = ' + timestamp + '\nseries "' + series + '"';

            });
```

I have to field `dates` and `data`, this second field is used to fill the value of "Mensagem" (fig1),but I can't parse this value from data. How can I parse this value from data source?

[image: Output example]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, have you done??